# How to rename files in a folder using the ls command output as a pipe ?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell

I am using GNU/Linux and BASH shell,

What i wanted to do is in server is to

i need to be able to download the files stating with B* and D* and then rename them to ~B* and ~D*(same file name just ~ in-front)

i wrote following which works fine for the downloading part ideally i would like it to use ls command output as well but dont know how to do that.

```
cd inbox
get D*
get B*
ls B*|rename $0 ~B.* 
bye
```

Any idea ?

**ideally what i would like to do is ls command to send the list of files one by one to the get command and then the once the get command is completed i want rename command executed renaming the server files**

Answer (score 1):

Do not execute this within your ftp session. Come out and execute it:

```
ls [BD]* | sed 's/.*/mv & ~&/' | sh
```

Comment: does anyone has any idea or any reference guide to what they mean in /s.*/ what is "s" i expect it a regular expression but i am used to php regular exp but this seems to be totally different... any link please for this ref ? i.e rename "s/ *//g" *.mp3

Comment: .* will match your entire file name and in the replacement section, mv command is generated. This mv command is executed using a shell.

Comment: Can you expound upon this?  Why is it so important to not execute within the ftp session.

Comment: @KronoS  my mistake, it can very well be part of the ftp session itself with an exclamation(!) in the beginning of ls.

Comment: If it is executed in the ftp session (without the !) then it will attempt to do the rename on the remote server, or just fail.

Comment: user1179459, the 's' character is the sed command "substitute", the search regexp is between the first and second '/' characters, and the replacement is between the second and third '/' characters.  Additional options can follow the third '/'.

Comment: May I ask here if there is a way to make the `rename` utility accept the results of piped commands as its file inputs? e.g. `ls | grep foo | rename 's/bar/baz/'`